# Swipeable Component State Being Passed Down to Other Items in List After Removing An Item

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-reanimated

I am creating a checkout screen with a list of checkout items. I am trying to implement a 'swipe to remove' feature for the checkout items if the user decides to delete an item from their cart.

I doing this using react-native-reanimated's 'Swipeable' component. The animation works fine, and my list items are getting removed properly, however, the 'remove container' is passed on to the checkout items below the one I removed, instead of just disappearing along with the removed item.

Here is my code for the checkout item component:

**CheckoutItem.tsx**

```
/* eslint-disable import/namespace */
import Ionicon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import * as Haptics from 'expo-haptics'
import { View, Text, Pressable, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { priceToText } from '../../Functions'
import { checkout } from '../../styles/CheckoutStyles'
import { MenuItem } from '../../store/slices/MenuItems'
import Animated, { useAnimatedGestureHandler, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring, withTiming } from "react-native-reanimated";
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";

interface Props {
  decUpdate: (menuItem: MenuItem) => void
  menuItem: MenuItem
  checkoutItem: any
  isDisabled: any
}

const CheckoutItem: any = ({ decUpdate, checkoutItem, isDisabled }: Props) => {
  const removeItem = () => {
    Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light)
    decUpdate(checkoutItem)
  }

  const rightSwipe = () => {
    return (
      <Pressable style={checkout.deleteContainer} onPress={removeItem}>
        <Text style={[checkout.deleteContainerText]}>Remove</Text>
      </Pressable>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {/* <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panGesture}> */}
        <Swipeable renderRightActions={rightSwipe}>
          <View style={[checkout.item]}>
            <Pressable
              disabled={isDisabled}
              onPress={removeItem}
              style={({ pressed }) => [{ opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1 }, checkout.icon]}
            >
              <Ionicon name="trash" size={20} color="#000" />
            </Pressable>
            <View style={checkout.NAME}>
              <Text style={checkout.itemNameText}>{checkoutItem.orderItem.item}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={checkout.PRICE}>
              <Text style={checkout.text}>{priceToText(checkoutItem.orderItem.price)}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Swipeable>
      {/* </PanGestureHandler> */}
    </View>
  )
}

export default CheckoutItem
```

and here is the code for my checkout cart screen

**CheckoutScreen.tsx**

```
const CheckoutScreen: React.FC<{ navigation: any }> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const {
    orderItems,
    isLoading: isLoadingOrderCart,
    college: collegeOrderCart,
    price,
  } = useAppSelector((state) => state.orderCart)
  const { currentUser } = useAppSelector((state) => state.currentUser)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(orderItems.length < 1)

  const updateDisabled = (b: boolean) => {
    navigation.setParams({
      disabled: b,
    })
    setDisabled(b)
  }

  const removeOrder = (newItem: OrderItem) => {
    const item = orderItems.find((item) => item.index == newItem.index)
    //problem is they all have the same id
    if (item === undefined) {
      throw new TypeError("Couldn't find orderItem to delete")
    }
    dispatch(removeOrderItem(item))
  }

  return (
    <View style={checkout.wrapper}>
      {isLoadingOrderCart ? (
        <View style={loading.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <StripeProvider publishableKey={stripePK}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={checkout.upperContainer}>
              <View style={checkout.header}>
                <Text style={checkout.totalText}>Order Summary:</Text>
              </View>
              <FlatList
                data={orderItems}
                renderItem={(item) => {
                  return <CheckoutItem decUpdate={removeOrder} checkoutItem={item.item} isDisabled={isDisabled}/>
                }}>
              </FlatList>
              <View style={checkout.footer}>
                <Text style={checkout.totalText}>Total: {priceToText(price)}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={checkout.lowerContainer}>
              <Pressable
                disabled={isDisabled}
                style={({ pressed }) => [
                  { backgroundColor: pressed ? '#222' : '#333', opacity: orderItems.length < 1 ? 0.7 : 1 },
                  checkout.checkoutButton,
                ]}
                onPress={() => {
                  updateDisabled(true)
                  makePayment()
                }}
              >
                <Text style={checkout.checkoutText}>Complete Order</Text>
                <Text style={checkout.paymentInformation}>
                  Because we are in beta, we will not save your card information
                </Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          </View>
        </StripeProvider>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

I want the item to just go away completely, and for the state of the other checkout items to remain the same as they were. It's strange because they are all separate components, so I don't understand how the animation is getting passed between them.

[Here](https://gyazo.com/dc3179415d1a5ca67d2971659758f3c2) is a gif of the issue.